# Upload file inside html table and fetch file data from every html table row using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, file, html-table

I've made a html table using jquery in which I'm asking user to upload files and enter their information. I'm successful in fetching every row data but with files I'm getting no data.

```
<button id="addfamilymember"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

               <table id="famMemTable" style="display:none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="required-field">First Name</th>
                            <th class="required-field">Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Mobile Number</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Attach Covid Card</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

jq$("#addfamilymember").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  
            jq$('#famMemTable').show();
            jq$('#deletefamilymember').show();
            var covidCard = "<td><label class='btn btn-default btn-sm center-block btn-file'> <i style='color:dodgerblue;padding:5px 10px;' class='fa fa-paperclip fa-2x paperClipIcon' aria-hidden='true'></i><input type='file' id='famMemCovidCard' style='display: none;'/><img id='previewFamMemCovidCard' style='display:none;width:50px; height:50px;margin-top:2px;'/></label></td>"
            var markup = "<tr class='item'><td><input type='text' class='famMemFrstName' id='famMemFrstName' placeholder='First name'/></td><td><input type='text' class='famMemLstName' id='famMemLstName' placeholder='Surname'/></td><td><input type='text' class='famMemEmail' id='famMemEmail' placeholder='Email'/></td><td><input class='famMemMobNum' type='text' id='famMemMobNum' placeholder='Mobile number'/></td><td><select class='famMemGender' id='slctGender'><option value='' selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Select Gender</option><option value='Male'>Male</option><option value='Female'>Female</option></select></td>" +covidCard + "<td><button id='deletefamilymember' class='deletefamilymember'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td></tr>";
            jq$("#famMemTable tbody").append(markup);
        });

jq$(document).on("click","#saveBtn",function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var famMemLst = new Array();
                 jq$("tr.item").each(function() {
                        var famMemFrstName = jq$(this).find("input.famMemFrstName").val();
                        var famMemLstName = jq$(this).find("input.famMemLstName").val();
                        var famMemEmail = jq$(this).find("input.famMemEmail").val();
                        var famMemMobNum = jq$(this).find("input.famMemMobNum").val();
                        var famMemGender = jq$(this).find("select.famMemGender").val();
                        var file = jq$(this).find('input.famMemCovidCard').files[0];
                        var attachmentName = file.name;    
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
                        attachment = window.btoa(this.result);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Kindly add the full code. Eg. `#addfamilymember` is nowhere to be found

Comment: Edited. Check now

Comment: What is this part `//fetch file data here` suppose to do? Kindly add the rest of the code and close the `"#saveBtn"` callback.